# Transpose multiple columns to rows in Java Dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, flatmap

I have a dataset in spark which has values like

| org_id | user_id | call_id | audio_bw | video_bw | share_bw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

I am able to transpose it into the following using multiple SQL queries, bit wanted to do it using code, if possible using `flatMap`

| org_id | user_id | call_id | type | bw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | audio | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | video | 3 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | share | 4 |

Comment: Can you share your SQL queries, so we can understand the logic and transform it to code.

Comment: I got some help from one of the answer and have posted the final solution I implemented @AbdennacerLachiheb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your dataset is called `data`, this:

```
data = data.select(
  col("org_id"), 
  col("user_id"), 
  col("call_id"),
  expr("stack(3, 'audio', audio_bw, 'video', video_bw, 'share', share_bw) as (type, bw)")
)
```

does what you want, the final output table:

```
+------+-------+-------+-----+---+
|org_id|user_id|call_id| type| bw|
+------+-------+-------+-----+---+
|     1|      1|      1|audio|  2|
|     1|      1|      1|video|  3|
|     1|      1|      1|share|  4|
+------+-------+-------+-----+---+
```

More about `stack` can be found [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#stack)!

**EDIT:**

In case you have multiple columns to stack:

```
data
  .select(
    col("org_id"),
    col("user_id"),
    col("call_id"),
    // concatinate your data
    expr("concat_ws(' - ', audio_rx_bw, audio_tx_bw)").as("audio"),
    expr("concat_ws(' - ', video_rx_bw, video_tx_bw)").as("video"),
    expr("concat_ws(' - ', share_rx_bw, share_tx_bw)").as("share")
  )
  .select(
    col("org_id"),
    col("user_id"),
    col("call_id"),
    // stack again, but this time for the concatenated values
    expr("stack(3, 'audio', audio, 'video', video, 'share', share) as (type, data)")
  )
  // once done with stacking, get the data in your desired format
  .withColumn("rx_bw", split(col("data"), " - ")(0))
  .withColumn("tx_bw", split(col("data"), " - ")(1))
  .drop("data")
```

Input:

```
+------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|org_id|user_id|call_id|audio_rx_bw|audio_tx_bw|video_rx_bw|video_tx_bw|share_rx_bw|share_tx_bw|
+------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|     1|      1|      1|          2|          3|          4|          2|          4|          5|
+------+-------+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Output:

```
+------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|org_id|user_id|call_id| type|rx_bw|tx_bw|
+------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
|     1|      1|      1|audio|    2|    3|
|     1|      1|      1|video|    4|    2|
|     1|      1|      1|share|    4|    5|
+------+-------+-------+-----+-----+-----+
```

for this input:

Comment: The stack works, but there is an issue. I did not give you the whole dataset. actually audio_bw column is further divided into 2 parts: audio_tx_bw and audio_rx_bw. And i cannot use 2 stacks in same query. Is there a workaround to that, similar is for video and share

Comment: What do you mean with 'further divided into 2 parts'? Can you share an example of what you want and what you need?

Comment: org_id, user_id, call_id, audio_rx_bw, audio_tx_bw, video_rx_bw, video_tx_bw, share_rx_bw, share_tx_bw
1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 5

This should be transformed like following

org_id, user_id, call_id, type, rx_bw, tx_bw
1, 1, 1, audio, 2, 3
1, 1, 1, video, 4, 2
1, 1, 1, share, 4, 5

Comment: updated the comment, hope it does the work you want

Comment: Yes that was helpful, seeing the split command I was able to modify my select queries and how I made sense of the data

Answer (score 0):

I used the following query and my issue was resolved

```
select 

   timestamp, organization_id, cluster_safe_name, node_name, correlation_id, is_cascade, cascade_peer_reachability, 

   stack(4, 'audio', audio_main_bitrate, 'audio_slides', audio_slides_bitrate, 'video', video_main_bitrate, 'share', video_slides_bitrate) as (call_type, rtp_bytes) 
from (
    select 
      timestamp, organization_id, cluster_safe_name, node_name, correlation_id, is_cascade, cascade_peer_reachability, 
      audio_main_rx_bitrate || '/' || audio_main_tx_bitrate as audio_main_bitrate, audio_slides_rx_bitrate  || '/' || audio_slides_tx_bitrate as audio_slides_bitrate, 
      video_main_rx_bitrate  || '/' || video_main_tx_bitrate as video_main_bitrate, video_slides_rx_bitrate  || '/' ||  video_slides_tx_bitrate as video_slides_bitrate 
    from homer_cascade_bandwidth_usage_metrics_v2 
    where timestamp >= '2022-07-20 10:20:00' and timestamp < '2022-07-20 11:00:00' 
) t

ORDER BY correlation_id
```